# HTML emails from oracle database

Tags: html, oracle, email

In my project, the requirement is to send HTML emails (notifications) from database (Oracle). I am using UTL_SMTP utility for the same. However the notification templates are needed to be stored in one of the database columns and each notification templates have HTML text and variables.

Please, find below the UTL_SMTP code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Email_Temp(
p_to            IN NVARCHAR2,
p_subject       IN NVARCHAR2,
p_template_id   IN Form_Templates.template_id%type)
RETURN          NVARCHAR2
AS
Ret_String      NVARCHAR2(10);
p_from          NVARCHAR2 (2000) := 'This is fixed(Database server)';
p_smtp_host     NVARCHAR2 (2000) := 'Database';
p_smtp_port     NUMBER := 25;
p_html_msg      NVARCHAR2 (4000) := NULL; 
l_mail_conn     UTL_SMTP.connection;
l_boundary      NVARCHAR2 (50) := '----=*#abc1234321cba#*=';
BEGIN

l_mail_conn := UTL_SMTP.open_connection (p_smtp_host, p_smtp_port);
UTL_SMTP.helo (l_mail_conn, p_smtp_host);
UTL_SMTP.mail (l_mail_conn, p_from);
UTL_SMTP.rcpt (l_mail_conn, p_to);
UTL_SMTP.open_data (l_mail_conn);
UTL_SMTP.write_data (l_mail_conn, 'From: ' || p_from || UTL_TCP.crlf);
UTL_SMTP.write_data (l_mail_conn, 'Sent: ' || TO_CHAR (SYSDATE,'FMDay, FMMonthDD, YYYY HH12:MI:SS PM') || UTL_TCP.crlf);
UTL_SMTP.write_data (l_mail_conn, 'To: ' || p_to || UTL_TCP.crlf);
UTL_SMTP.write_data (l_mail_conn, 'Subject: ' || p_subject || UTL_TCP.crlf);
UTL_SMTP.write_data (l_mail_conn, 'Reply-To: ' || p_from || UTL_TCP.crlf);
UTL_SMTP.write_data (l_mail_conn, 'MIME-Version: 1.0' || UTL_TCP.crlf);
UTL_SMTP.write_data (l_mail_conn
                  , 'Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="' || l_boundary || '"' || UTL_TCP.crlf
                    || UTL_TCP.crlf
                   );

IF p_html_msg IS NOT NULL
THEN
select html_string into p_html_msg from Form_Templates where template_id = p_template_id;
  UTL_SMTP.write_data (l_mail_conn, '--' || l_boundary || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  UTL_SMTP.write_data (l_mail_conn, 'Content-Type: text/html; charset="iso-8859-1"' || UTL_TCP.crlf || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  UTL_SMTP.write_data (l_mail_conn, p_html_msg);
  UTL_SMTP.write_data (l_mail_conn, UTL_TCP.crlf || UTL_TCP.crlf);
END IF;

UTL_SMTP.write_data (l_mail_conn, '--' || l_boundary || '--' || UTL_TCP.crlf);
UTL_SMTP.close_data (l_mail_conn);
UTL_SMTP.quit (l_mail_conn);
Ret_String := 'Sucess';
RETURN Ret_String;
END;
/
```

Now, each templates which are going to be stored in the database columns (with fixed text and variables) look like below sample:

```
<html>
<body>
<h4 style="color:blue;">Assignee Notification</h4><br>
Hello Assignee,
<br><br>
You have been assigned a document.
<br><br>
<font size="3" color="blue"><b>Project Name:</b></font> variable
<br>
<font size="3" color="blue"><b>Document Nickname: </b></font> variable
<br><br>
</body>
</html>
```

I need to call the templates of mail function but at the same time, templates should contain the fixed text and variables with values.

Answer (score 0):

Here is code I wrote that does what you want.  This is not the most elegant solution and does not extend easily where you have multiple fields to be replaced.
It requires an email template table listing all the templates and a child locale table which has the boilerplate text in as many languages as you need.  The essence of the idea is to set up your template so that strings you need replaced are indicated with a text string like 'XXXXXXXX' or 'YYYYYYYY'.

```
   PROCEDURE Send_assignment_mail (to_user_in      IN NUMBER,
                                   by_user_in      IN NUMBER := NULL,
                                   case_id_in      IN NUMBER,
                                   case_type_in    IN NUMBER,
                                   mail_type_in    IN NUMBER := NULL,
                                   extra_text_in   IN VARCHAR2 := NULL)
   IS
      /******************************************************************************
      PURPOSE: sends an assignment email with link
      ******************************************************************************/
      v_user_email            VARCHAR2 (200);
      v_locale_id             NUMBER (10); --the language of the user
      v_byuser_name           VARCHAR2 (4000);
      v_subject               VARCHAR2 (200);
      v_body                  VARCHAR2 (4000);
      v_file_no               VARCHAR2 (40);
      v_weblink               VARCHAR2 (250);
      v_mail_type             NUMBER (10);
      --email type is for assignment emails in email_template table
      c_email_type   CONSTANT NUMBER (1) := 1;
      c_replace      CONSTANT VARCHAR2 (8) := 'XXXXXXXX';
   BEGIN
      --set a default template if none is provided
      IF mail_type_in IS NULL
      THEN
         v_mail_type := c_email_type;
      ELSE
         v_mail_type := mail_type_in;
      END IF;

      --get the language the user wishes to receive the email in
      SELECT cmu.email, cmu.locale_id
        INTO v_user_email, v_locale_id
        FROM app_user cmu
       WHERE cmu.ID = to_user_in;

      v_byuser_name := Get_by_user_name (by_user_in, v_locale_id);


      --get more information about the item you are notifying them about
      v_file_no := GET_FILE_NUM (case_id_in, case_type_in);

      SELECT emi.subject,
                REPLACE (emi.text1, c_replace, v_file_no)
             || UTL_TCP.CRLF
             || UTL_TCP.CRLF
             || REPLACE (emi.text2, c_replace, v_byuser_name)
             || UTL_TCP.CRLF
             || UTL_TCP.CRLF
             || v_weblink
             || UTL_TCP.CRLF
             || UTL_TCP.CRLF
             || extra_text_in
        INTO v_subject, v_body
        FROM EMAIL_TEMPLATE_LOCALE emi
       WHERE EMI.PK_ID = v_mail_type AND EMI.LOCALE_ID = v_locale_id;

      --call your generic mail procedure 
      MAIL_PKG.SEND (g_from,
                              v_user_email,
                              NULL,
                              v_subject,
                              v_body);
      --log that you sent the mail so if the user denies receiving it
      --you have something to show
      LOG_EMAIL (to_user_in,
                 v_mail_type,
                 v_subject,
                 case_id_in);
   END Send_assignment_mail;
```

Comment: Your solution is quite useless you don't provide the code (or any other source) for package `MAIL_PKG`.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit The OP is not asking how to send email. They are asking how to modify templates in an email.